# How I can load arrays with integers?

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I want when user choose from listview an item (Brand name device),load data arrays with integers. I try to make a remote control.The application must load arrays for power,channel up,down,vol up,vol down functions.How i can do this?I have one listview(devices) and buttons power,Volume,Channel.
Every button use one array with integers for IR pulses.

```
    private OnClickListener btnSendChanUpListener = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(run==0) {
            run = 1;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    int[] mod1ChanUpX1 = {346,173,......};//Channel up X1 device

                    try {

                        SendIRcommand( frequency, mod1ChanUpX1 );

                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {

                         Log.e( "Error transmitting...");
                    }

                    run=0;
            }}).start();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What have you done so far? You need to provide some code fragments or something that you have tried and doesn't work. You will not get people to write code for you here.

Comment: @maverick1989 that doesn't sound right. plenty of people are happy to write code on SO. it is definitely constructive to ask a poster for what they have tried. and also to inform that doing so will help answering the question. but it is a blatant misrepresentation that people will not write code for you here -- they will do so, enthusiastically. (ps: not you specifically, but in general, why are new users considered fair game for bullying? that's the only term i can think of that best captures the general phenomenon.)

Comment: @randomstring uh no plenty of people are happy to look over code and correct any mistakes they find. You cannot expect someone to say "Can you please tell me how to do A and B. thanks... " and then expect people to come write code. Until OP had edited his question, there was no code. For all you know, they could have come here without trying anything and asked a question. By simply giving them code, it does not facilitate learning. Users will simply copy the code from here and paste it into their project. They will also ask us to do their homework then.

Comment: @maverick1989 i sympathize with your goal, but the reality is that many people on SO will actually do homework. the only person harmed in an abstract way by this practice is the OP, and perhaps the OP's classmates if it is a bell-curve graded class. So does not, as far as i know, have any policy against this. you are welcome to voice your concern, but it does not seem right to misinform the user. and as i originally said, it is perfectly fair to ask the OP to post code "what have you tried?" and that was a good thing that you did.

Comment: @randomstring Then we agree to disagree. I do not believe, as you say, that SO explicitly states that users cannot simply give code. However, by supporting such behavior, it is encouraged. And it is not just the OP that is harmed. Anyone who wants to find an answer to that question can simply copy code. There is no way of knowing how many came to that post and copied that code fragment without bothering to understand what it did.

Comment: @maverick1989 i was making a rather narrow point, the bulk of your original comment is perfectly fine. in fact, for this question, it would be impossible to even understand it without the code. i am probably being pedantic based on what i see other new users facing in other situations where the question is clear but people still admonish them wrongly. no sweat, no offense intended to you. if i were to rephrase my original point, i would have suggested rephrasing the last sentence of your first comment to: "your question doesn't make sense the way it is, but with some code it might".

Comment: @randomstring I was not offended. I can see what you are trying to say.